# Tradurre "Membership" o "Memberships", "Member" in assenza di contesto

Tags: translation, english-comparison

Come tradurreste "Membership" o "Memberships" in assenza di contesto?

Devo tradurre cose come "User Membership" o "Membership Plan" in un software per gestire "Memberships" in modo molto astratto.

Come rendere in Italiano "una persona parte di una 'Membership'"? Sarebbe "Membro", ma, a parte un sottile ma equivoco riferimento andrologico, non c'è un corrispondente di quest'ultimo (Membro) per "Membership" (il membro è parte di "una..."? cosa? associazione, istituzione, società, gruppo, ecc. sono altre parole con altre radici).

Suppongo si potrebbero usare, in assenza di contesto, "iscrizione" e "iscritto", ma non sono convinto. Vorrei evitare "associazione" e "associato" (o socio), perché mi sembrano propendere troppo in un contesto di associazione commerciale, societario.

Vorrei dei termini più neutrali possibili per connotare l'appartenenza ad un gruppo e qualificare l'appartenente al gruppo senza usare termini o espressioni lunghe e contorte come queste che ho appena utilizzato (anche la sola parola gruppo non va bene).

Grazie delle opinioni in merito!

Comment: È quasi impossibile tradurre “in assenza di contesto”. Già san Girolamo (non sono religioso, è che lui tradusse la bibbia e scrisse cose interessanti sulla traduzione) scriveva, più o meno, che non si traduce parola per parola ma discorso per discorso. Nel tuo caso, non sapendo – per le esigenze astratte che dici – di che cosa stiamo parlando, forse andrà bene “iscrizione/iscritto” e forse no, forse “abbonamento/abbonato” e forse no, forse “appartenenza/appartenente” e forse no; forse ancora socio, affiliato, partecipante, ... e relativi nomi astratti.

Comment: astratto per astratto consiglierei comunità

Comment: “Comunità” è interessante, @JoeTaras, ma non so se qui funziona: mi sembra che si parli di essere iscritti/associati/aderenti... a qualcosa e quindi credo che serva una parola che denoti semmai l'appartenenza alla comunità, non la comunità in sé.

Comment: Continuando il brainstorming: qualcosa di ancor più astratto come “situazione”, “posizione” o simili?

Comment: @DaG: Si, hai ragione, purtroppo è difficile dare un significato senza un contesto specifico

Comment: Magari *appartenenza* può essere usato in svariati contesti.

Comment: grazie a tutti - affiliazione/affiliato e abbonamento/abbonato vengono usati in contesti leggermente diversi nel mio caso e non posso usarli (abbonamento presume una sottoscrizione, che nel mio caso non c'è). Probabile che iscrizione/iscritto rimangano, per esclusione, quelli preferibili. Associazione/associato ci può stare semanticamente ma non mi piace molto :/

Answer (score 3):

Ciao Unfulvio,

Affiliazione e adesione sono le parole più italiane per dire membership. Allora potresti dire:

> una persona parte di un'affiliazione (o piuttosto: un affiliato)

Puoi dare un'occhiata qui: http://www.linguee.it/italiano-inglese/search?source=auto&query=membership

Comment: “Affiliazione” sa un po' di massoneria, ma è un'alternativa interessante; il sostantivo corrispondente è “affiliato” (non “una persona parte...”). E per “adesione” si potrebbe usare “aderente”.

Answer (score 1):

Senza contesto è difficile tradurre in italiano perché l'inglese si basa sul contesto della frase per esprimere il significato di una parola mentre in italiano il più delle volte le parole sono meno generiche e più specifiche per intendere un dato concetto.

Direi che una traduzione più generica sarebbe *Membro* per *Member* e *Sottoscrizione* per *Membership*. Anche *Affiliazione* può essere usato anche se comporta un diverso livello di partecipazione da parte del membro in alcuni casi.

Answer (score -2):

> SOTTOSCRIZIONE = MEMBERSHIP
>
> SOTTOSCRIZIONI = MEMBERSHIPS
>
> MEMBRO oppure SOTTOSCRIVENTE = MEMBER

Tutto nasce dal fatto che Membership e Subscription in italiano hanno significato analogo, è un raro caso inverso perchè in realtà avviene più spesso il contrario cioè che una parola inglese abbia diverse traduzioni in contesti diversi in Italiano.

Comment: Puoi argomentare meglio la tua risposta?